# Selecting images inside nested tables using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying to use Watir to scrape a page which has AJAX-generated tables. As each level of the table is expanded, additional nested tables are inserted and the expand link moves in one level. The number of levels is not always the same. The end result is something like this, loaded in asynchronously one layer at a time:

```
<table>
    Data Type 1
    <table>
        <table>
            <table>
                <a href="javascript:ajaxCall();"><img src="expand.gif" /></a>
            </table>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
<table>
    Data Type 2
    <table>
        <table>
            <table>
                <a href="javascript:ajaxCall(1);"><img src="expand.gif" /></a>
                <a href="javascript:ajaxCall(2);"><img src="expand.gif" /></a>
            </table>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
```

I want to interact only with the table containing "Data Type 1." The table IDs are randomly generated (this is an annoying ASP.net application), so the only thing to select on is "Data Type 1."

Thus, I have:

```
while browser.table(:text => /Type 1/).image(:src => "expand.gif").present?
    links = browser.table(:text => /Type 1/).images(:src => "expand.gif")
    links.each do |li|
        li.click
    end
end
```

This works fine to expand the first nested table (with the `expand.gif` directly inside the `table` element that contains the selector text. However, the next layer of tables does not expand--clearly, my selector isn't going into child tables.

If I leave out the table selector altogether, the code will happily expand every nested table on the page until it runs out of levels, but I only want "Data Type 1."

Any suggestions how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of watir are you using?

Comment: If you add some debugging code in there such as `puts "the number of links is: #{links.size}"`  it might help to see what is going on.     The other thing is if these expand links are being created on the fly, you might want a little sleep, like a half second or so, right before the end of the while loop to give the client side code some time to render the links or turn them visible

Comment: What does the HTML look like once you have expanded the Type 1 table - ie what does it look like with the nested tables?